# "format" doesn't work with a specific date format

Tags: excel, vba, date, datepicker

I can format a date in a specific date format, but the formatted string seems not possible to format anymore.
It wouldn't be a problem, because I could save the old format. But the thing is that I also have to read a string in the specific format from an excel cell and format it.

I use the german date system. (Mi = Wednesday)

```
UI_Main.txt_BeginnDatum.Value = Format(UI_Date_Picker.Date_Picker.Value, "ddd dd mmm yyyy")
```

That's how I get the date from the datepicker. It's now formatted in the specific date format I'm talking about (Mi. 09 Jan 2019).
The default format from the picker is dd.mm.yyyy.

```
strBeginDate_g = txt_BeginnDatum.Value

strTemp = strTemp & "Nr. " & Format(strBeginDate_g, "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

Here I try to write the date in another format, but the output is just the same as before.

Of course I could write my own function but I am sure format is supposed to handle this.

Comment: There's very little to chew on IMO. It's not clear where `strBeginDate_g` is coming from, what its value is, how it relates to `UI_Main.txt_BeginnDatum.Value`, or what "output" is referring to. Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: The *Format()* function will apply a format to **numbers** only.  If you attempt to format a value and the operation only returns the same as input, then the value is probably *Text*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom format, like so

```
Function FormatYYYYMMDD(strDateIn As String) As Date

Dim a() As String
Dim s As String

a = Split(strDateIn, Chr(32))
a(0) = vbNullString

FormatYYYYMMDD = CDate(Format(a(1) & "/" & a(2) & "/" & a(3), "yyyy-mm-dd"))

Erase a

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Format function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) can only format a numeric value. But you give it a string `strBeginDate_g` as parameter.

Instead give it the value as parameter:

```
strTemp = strTemp & "Nr. " & Format$(UI_Date_Picker.Date_Picker.Value, "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

Once you formatted a date with `Format()` it becomes a string, and you cannot calculate anymore with a string nor can you format it again.

Comment: But when I save the date from the picker as dd.mm.yyy, It works to format the same again in yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: @livior thats only because VBA casts the string `dd.mm.yyyy` automatically into a date because it cannot handle the string at all and then formats that into as string again. You cannot rely on that, because it highly depends on the default date format that is set for the operating system. Always use numeric values of the dates (or variables of type `date`) to calculate with them or format them. Otherwise you never know what you get.

Comment: Ok. Is it possible to cast this "Mi. 09 Jan 2019" into a date variable? I think I tried to cast string to date but I got type errors. Otherwise I guess I have to parse char for char...

Comment: @livior Why would you do that if you have the value of the date `UI_Date_Picker.Date_Picker.Value`? So use that numeric value instead of inventing a parser. If you need to convert date --> string --> date --> string then you are doing it definitely wrong.

Comment: The vba tool contains a user interface to set all data for a formular. When u press "save" the tool writes the data into the cells of the premade formular. But you can also open the excel file and edit the values with the tool. That's why I need to parse the data from the cells. The date is stored in the same cell as the time (Date -> new line -> Time).

Comment: If you save the date into a cell, don't save it as string save it as date value (numeric) and format the cell using [Range.NumberFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.numberformat) for example: `cell.value = UI_Date_Picker.Date_Picker.Value` and then `cell.NumberFormat = "ddd dd mmm yyyy"`. This way the cell actually contains a date value but shows it in the desired format. This cell value can be used in `format` then. Just never convert dates into strings if you can avoid that, instead format them with numberformat. Anything else is doing it wrong.